# jQuery post call with codeigniter fails

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to delete the element with post jquery request:

```
$(function(){
    //The element
   // <a data-id="39" data-toggle="modal" href="#delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i> 

Delete</a>


   $('.delete').on('click',function(){
       var id= $(this).attr('data-id');


  $.post('task/delete',  { id: id }, function(data) {
        alert('Task deleted!');
    })
    .success(function(){  alert('Task deleted!'); })          
     .complete(function(){  alert('Task completed!'); })
     .error(function(){   alert('Error was found!'); });
   })

});
```

My controller is called task and the function inside it is called delete.

```
  class Task extends CI_Controller {

        public function delete()
    {
        $this->load->model('tasks_model','task_delete');
        $this->task_delete-> deleteTask($_POST['id']);

    }
     }
```

The model is quite simple.. it simply deletes the record.

```
    public function deleteTask($task_id)
    {
        $task_id = mysql_real_escape_string($task_id);
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ?", array($task_id));

    }
```

I get two messages..one is error and one is delete...
Another thing that I want to avoid is someone posting the id to the controller task .. which will delete the records one by one automatically, is there a way to avoid this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method should look something like this

```
public function delete()
{
   // Do user validation here
  $this->load->model('tasks_model');
  $this->tasks_model->task_delete($this->input->post('id'));
  return "task deleted";
}
```

And you models method like this

```
public function task_delete($task_id)
{
  $this->db->where('task_id', $task_id);
  $this->db->delete('tasks');
}
```

As I would recommend validating the user where the comment says you should, and using CI's active record library where you can to increase portability to a different DB.

**Edit**

To show PHP errors (and maybe MySQL errors if they are turned on).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To ensure the task is deleted, do this (which is not as efficient).

```
public function task_delete($task_id)
{
  $this->db->where('task_id', $task_id);
  $this->db->delete('tasks');

  $this->db->from('tasks');
  $this->db->where('task_id', $task_id);

  $query = $this->db->get();

  if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
  {
    return FALSE;
  } 
  else return TRUE;
}
```

And then do something with the returned boolean in the controller.

Comment: I did what you told me.. how do I display sql errors?..while having the ajax request.. how do I know that the sql execution was successful or not?!?

Comment: To monitor your AJAX requests, you can right click anywhere on the page, select the "Inspect Element" menu item, and on the new window that opens, select "Network". There you'll be able to see exactly what you send and what you get back in your AJAX calls. (if a lot of calls are being made, you can select "XHR" at the bottom to only see AJAX calls).

Comment: okay, I will try that now..It isnt sql error..cause I deleted the sql code... it is something in the controller

Comment: Even when I mark all the code out..with this //... it still seems to overload and crash...why?!? I have several delete buttons..may be the jquery calls the $.post for each ?!?

Comment: No sure why it would crash - code looks ok, other than you have no "delete" class on your anchor in the jQuery in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used the function name in your controller it should be:

```
$this->task_delete->deleteTask($id);
```

Comment: it gives me 404..when i send the request...by chrome

Comment: use $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>task/delete')

Comment: Thats okay, I put the full url.. it returns 200..but chrome goes blank..it displays a message saying that something wrong goes with the page...

Comment: Usually you can avoid using $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>task/delete') and you can just put $.post('/task/delete') (note the / at the start). The / at the start will work as long as you aren't trying to run the website in a subdirectory (http://www.example.com/blog/tasks).

Comment: use echo instead of return as ajax requests get the response through echo and another thing i noticed is that your delete query has syntax error you havent put the id in where clause

Comment: I made the changes..see above.. it waits 13.91s and crashes.. file transfer before it crashes is: 214mb

Comment: and did you try it in other browsers?

Comment: I think there is a timeout...I tried again..it stopped around the same time... firefox doesnt do anything..or shows anything..I need a way to display the php error somehow

Comment: yeah, I emptied the function and did  echo "Deleted";  why is there such a long wait and crash..Even when the function is empty it does that

Comment: I think , I know why it crashes..it doesnt find the function

Answer (score 1):

To avoid someone posting all IDs and deleting all tasks, you should only delete tasks which belong to this user.

I'm guessing you save each task so it belongs to a specific user, right? So in your delete query, you can make it so you run a DELETE WHERE task_id={task_id} AND user_id={user_id}. The user_id is something you'll have saved in the session.

As a side note, when running database queries, you can bind the parameters, which means CI takes care of making the parameters safe. So you can amend your query above to be like this:

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ?", array($task_id));
```

You can read more on this here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html at the bottom (Query Bindings section).

As for your error of getting both an error and a success message, there might be a few different things going wrong. I'm not sure if something's gone wrong when copying the code, but you have an error in the PHP code:

```
$this->load->model('tasks_model','task_delete');
$this->task_delete($id);
```

Should be:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id'); // the data is posted, it won't be passed in as an argument to the controller function
$this->load->model('tasks_model','task_delete');
$this->task_delete->deleteTask($id);
```

And your query also seems to have a mistake, so it would be better to make it as I mentioned above.

Comment: lol..I made the corrections.. it waits a few seconds..and then chrome crashes..how do I debug this

Comment: That's quite odd. I can't imagine why it would crash the browser. As suggested by Shayan above as well, you should change return "task deleted"; to be echo "task deleted";. I know this probably won't help much, but maybe try it in another browser?